# How can I let run this Select over all LD stored in the test Table?

Tags: mysql, join

would be one so kind and help me or let me learn how to do this problem?
I have following mini demo table:

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
     CREATE TABLE `test` (
       `recid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `ScopusTI` varchar(855) DEFAULT NULL,
       `BIOGRAPHYTITLE` varchar(855) DEFAULT NULL,
       `LD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
       `BIOTIrecid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`recid`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

     -- ----------------------------
     -- Records of test
     -- ----------------------------
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('0', 'T1',     'T1a', '1', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('99', 'T1',     'T1b', '1', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('461', 'T2',   'T2aa', '2', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('3550', 'T3',  'T3a', '1', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('4202', 'T4',  'T4aa', '2', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('4979', 'T5',  'T5a', '1', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('10270', 'T6', 'T6aa', '2', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('17159', 'T7', 'T7aa', '2', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('23358', 'T8', 'T8a', '1', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('24113', 'T9', 'T9aa', '2', null);
     INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('26326', 'T10', 'T10a', '1', null);
```

And now I would like to make this select over all LDs in the Database: THis select works fine for t4.LD=1 but I also want t4.LD=2 or t4.LD=3 ....etc.

```
     SELECT 
      t1.recid,
      t1.ScopusTI,
     BIOGRAPHYTITLE   ,t1.LD ,count(*) as az,t3.myrecids
     FROM test t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD`+0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM test GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
     inner join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(recid) as myrecids , ScopusTI ,convert(LD,UNSIGNED) SELLD, t4.LD  from test t4 where t4.LD = 1 GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI and t3.LD = t2.MINLD 
     GROUP BY ScopusTI ORDER BY az desc, t1.`LD`+0 ;
```

I think it would be done with a join. But how?
I would be thankfull if I could learn from the solution again.
Thanks

EDIT:
I tried this but here the az column is not correct:

```
     SELECT 
         t1.recid,
         t1.ScopusTI,
         BIOGRAPHYTITLE   ,t1.LD ,count(*) as az,t3.myrecids
     FROM test t1
     cross join (select LD from test) tc
     INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD`+0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM test GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
     inner join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(recid) as myrecids , ScopusTI ,convert(LD,UNSIGNED) SELLD, t4.LD  from test t4 GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI and t3.LD = t2.MINLD and t3.LD=tc.LD
     GROUP BY ScopusTI ORDER BY az desc, t1.`LD`+0 ;
```

The correct and desired result should be this

[image: desired Solution]

When I do the explicit solution with two LDs that would be like this:

```
   drop TABLE if EXISTS atest;
   create table atest (select * from test);

   SELECT * from(
   SELECT 
       t1.recid,
       t1.ScopusTI,
      t1.BIOGRAPHYTITLE   ,t1.LD ,count(*) as az,t3.myrecids
   FROM atest t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD`+0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM atest GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
   inner join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(recid) as myrecids , ScopusTI ,convert(LD,UNSIGNED) SELLD, t4.LD  from atest t4 where t4.LD='1' GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI and t3.LD = t2.MINLD 
   GROUP BY ScopusTI ORDER BY az desc, t1.`LD`+0 )ts1 
   UNION (
   SELECT 
       t1.recid,
       t1.ScopusTI,
      t1.BIOGRAPHYTITLE   ,t1.LD ,count(*) as az,t3.myrecids
   FROM atest t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(`LD`+0) MINLD,ScopusTI FROM atest GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
   inner join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(recid) as myrecids , ScopusTI ,convert(LD,UNSIGNED) SELLD, t4.LD  from atest t4 where t4.LD='2' GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI and t3.LD = t2.MINLD 
   GROUP BY ScopusTI ORDER BY az desc, t1.`LD`+0 );
```

And you can see the correct and desired table.

[image: correct table]

The purpose is matching similarity (LD=LevenshteinDistance) between BIOTitles and ScopusTIs.

EDIT: one little bug I found in nbk`s answer when I let it run on my big table:

The `group by ScopusTI` at the second inner join should be replaced by `group by LD,ScopusTI`

so this is now working as it should:

```
   SELECT 
       t1.recid,
       t1.ScopusTI,
       BIOGRAPHYTITLE,
       t1.LD,
       t5.az AS az,
       t3.myrecids
   FROM
       test t1
           CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT 
           LD
       FROM
           test) tc
           INNER JOIN
       (SELECT 
           MIN(`LD` + 0) MINLD, ScopusTI
       FROM
           test
       GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI
           AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
           INNER JOIN
       (SELECT 
           GROUP_CONCAT(recid) AS myrecids,
               ScopusTI,
               CONVERT( LD , UNSIGNED) SELLD,
               t4.LD
       FROM
           test t4
       GROUP BY LD,ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI
           AND t3.LD = t2.MINLD
           AND t3.LD = tc.LD
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT
            COUNT(ScopusTI) AS az,
            ScopusTI, LD
        FROM test
        GROUP BY ScopusTI,LD
        ) t5 ON t1.ScopusTI = t5.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t5.LD   
   GROUP BY ScopusTI
   ORDER BY az DESC , t1.`LD` + 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the desired result.

But i don't see what difference it would make if you had 2 or 10 LDs.

The number of ScopusTI are now counted for the complete all rows, with out differencing between LD, that because T1 didn't appear in 2.

```
SELECT 
    t1.recid,
    t1.ScopusTI,
    BIOGRAPHYTITLE,
    t1.LD,
    t5.az AS az,
    t3.myrecids
FROM
    test t1
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        LD
    FROM
        test) tc
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MIN(`LD` + 0) MINLD, ScopusTI
    FROM
        test
    GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI
        AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(recid) AS myrecids,
            ScopusTI,
            CONVERT( LD , UNSIGNED) SELLD,
            t4.LD
    FROM
        test t4
    GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI
        AND t3.LD = t2.MINLD
        AND t3.LD = tc.LD
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         COUNT(ScopusTI) AS az,
         ScopusTI
     FROM test
     GROUP BY ScopusTI
     ) t5 ON t1.ScopusTI = t5.ScopusTI   
GROUP BY ScopusTI
ORDER BY az DESC , t1.`LD` + 0;
```

After some consideration and your insisting on the different LDs.

This also only count ScorpusTI per LD. As it gets the same result, but would differ when the same ScorTI correlates with different LS

```
SELECT 
    t1.recid,
    t1.ScopusTI,
    BIOGRAPHYTITLE,
    t1.LD,
    t5.az AS az,
    t3.myrecids
FROM
    test t1
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        LD
    FROM
        test) tc
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MIN(`LD` + 0) MINLD, ScopusTI
    FROM
        test
    GROUP BY ScopusTI) t2 ON t1.ScopusTI = t2.ScopusTI
        AND t1.LD = t2.MINLD
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(recid) AS myrecids,
            ScopusTI,
            CONVERT( LD , UNSIGNED) SELLD,
            t4.LD
    FROM
        test t4
    GROUP BY ScopusTI) t3 ON t1.ScopusTI = t3.ScopusTI
        AND t3.LD = t2.MINLD
        AND t3.LD = tc.LD
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         COUNT(ScopusTI) AS az,
         ScopusTI, LD
     FROM test
     GROUP BY ScopusTI,LD
     ) t5 ON t1.ScopusTI = t5.ScopusTI AND t1.LD = t5.LD   
GROUP BY ScopusTI
ORDER BY az DESC , t1.`LD` + 0;
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! Great done, and I could compare your result with mine try and found that I was near the solution. Have learnt again a lot!

Comment: see my correction to your answer. I can not explain why but on my big table I had to do this correction.

Comment: no it makes sense, but i didn't write that part ;) verything has to be grouped by LD and Scorpusti, so that you can join them corredctly.